# Objects placed inside classes to be rendered with OpenGL

Tags: c++, class, opengl, c++11, opengl-3

I began to learn OpenGL about a week ago and I now want to create a mesh class. The code I'm about to show gives me a black screen (that's the color I fill it with).

I basically stripped the code from my main function and placed it inside a class, it worked inside main.

mesh.cpp

```
    #include "mesh.h"

mesh::mesh(std::vector<GLfloat> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> indices)
{
    this->vertices = vertices;
    this->indices = indices;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &triangleBuffer);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), this->vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), this->indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

}

mesh::~mesh()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &triangleBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
}

void mesh::update(){
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

mesh.h

```
    #ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class mesh
{
    public:
        mesh(std::vector<GLfloat> vertices, std::vector<GLuint> triangles);
        ~mesh();
        void update();
    protected:
    private:
        GLuint vertexArrayObject, vertexBuffer, triangleBuffer;
        std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
        std::vector<GLuint> indices;
};

#endif // MESH_H
```

According to [this](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Model-Loading/Mesh), this should be the correct way to do it (?).

BTW, all this code is a mashup from [this](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Model-Loading/Mesh) and [open.gl](http://open.gl) sites, here are the variables I pass into the constructor.

For the vertices:

```
    std::vector<GLfloat> vertices = {
//  Position        Color             Texcoords
-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};
```

and the indices:

```
    std::vector<GLuint> elements = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};
```

Also please note that I changed the code snippets according to Anton's suggestions, that didn't seem to work

Comment: Where are your calls to `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`, etc. by the way? Those are important, but completely absent.

Comment: @Anton They are in my main function, do I need them in this class?  The glVertexAttribPointer are set up correctly, I did not change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You have two problems that immediately come to mind:

1. `this->triangles.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)`

   This problem will not affect anything because `GLfloat` has the same size as `GLuint`, but if that was not a typo, it indicates to me you may be thinking about the index buffer wrong.

   - Make this `triangles.size () * sizeof (GLuint)` for consistency.
2. `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, this->vertices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);`

   You have two separate lists in your class, `vertices` and `triangles`, and this call only cares about the size of one of those.

   - `triangles` is an array of indices that makes a list of triangles (3 indices per-triangle).

   When you draw your elements array, you pass the number of elements in that list, not the number of vertices in your mesh.

---

While not technically a problem, I think you use `this->` a little bit too much when you write your code.

It is useful when you have variables at one scope that have the same name as members in your class *(which one could argue builds a case for inadequately descriptive names)*, but completely unnecessary in functions like `mesh::~mesh()`. It makes your code harder to read (for me anyway) because the lines are much longer.

Following the theme of inadequately descriptive names, by calling your index array "`triangles`" you have inadvertently limited this mesh class to drawing triangles. That might be a good variable name for a specialized constructor that builds a triangle mesh, but not so much for a class member. If you use `indices` instead, that gets rid of the name collision and the need to qualify everything using `this->`.

Comment: The this-> comes from the fact that I've been doing quite a bit of PHP recently, thanks for pointing that out and the GLfloat instead of HLuint was a typo!

Comment: @Tritzium: Even with those changes, you are still missing the necessary calls to `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` as I mentioned in a previous comment. Those API calls connect your vertex buffer's data to the actual attribute slots used by vertex shaders. Without them, the only thing you did was upload some data to the GPU. Keep in mind said calls need to come _after_ you bind your vertex array and vertex buffer, because they use whatever vertex buffer is bound when they're called to create a pointer and the vertex array object stores this pointer.

Comment: @Anton Thank you for all the help! I didn't realize I needed to setup the glVertexAttribPointer's for every "mesh". I solved it now, thank you again!